# What are the possible *root causes* of a SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: java, android, exceptions, http, sockets

I understand that a SocketTimeoutException (I'm in Java, but I guess it's the same in just about every major language) happens after a server or client doesn't respond after a period of time, let say 10 seconds.

I know it can happen if, let's say, the client sends a request to the server, and that request takes a long time to process (for instance, a long series of Inserts in a database). After a while, the client throws a SocketTimeoutException.

In that example, the *root cause* would be that the server had a request taking longer to process than the timeout limit.

What are other possible *root causes*? For instance, could the client, after sending a request to the server, fail to "catch" the response from the server *because of poor internet connection* and thus throw a SocketTimeoutException? Could the server fail to receive the response from the client (because of poor internet connection) and then the client, thinking the server isn't responding, throw a SocketTimeoutException?

For what it's worth, I'm working with okhttp3.OkHttpClient in Java, but I'm also interested in a general response.

For context, I'm working on an Android app that regularly gets SocketTimeoutExceptions when syncing data with a server, and I'm trying to understand the *underlying* different reasons (root causes) this exception gets thrown, so as to be able to properly handle it.

I did Google searches, but I'm having trouble finding explanations deeper than "the server (or client) failed to respond within the timeout limit".

Thanks.

Comment: Identifying root causes requires specific context and knowledge of the particular system and environment you're working in (network infrastructure, system architecture, OS or platform configuration, 3rd party software and providers, libraries/frameworks, and the apps themselves).    Once armed with a reasonably complete picture of the end-to-end path of the packet from source to destination you can start to identify particular device hops and processes along the way and check each of those to narrow down the location of the problem (and indeed whether it's something under your control or not)

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, a socket times out when the server or client fails to respond within the timeout limit.  There are many varying causes for this.  The only thing you know for certain is that:

- The server is or service is not actively refusing connections
- Something else in the networking layer is wrong
- Perhaps the other service is taking too long to calculate results

Some possible causes for timeout exceptions include:

- The service you called has received the request, but is taking a long time to send data back.  In order to get a timeout exception, no packets must be returned before the timeout triggers.
- TCP/IP settings are not configured correctly (hard coded DNS server and that server has been changed to a new IP)
- The server is not running
- Firewall settings are dropping packets rather than terminating the connection
- Typo in the target host name or IP address resulting in the server attempting to access a resource that is not there
- There is no service listening on the specified port

It's something that requires further investigation.  The Java process can't know if your target server has a typo or if the server is simply not present.  The TCP stack will attempt to resend packets until the configured timeout.  If the TCP stack can detect that the resource is present and is not responding (i.e. actively terminating requests), then you'll see a different exception.

There's no silver bullet, and I've experienced all of the different causes I listed above in different projects.  Hopefully it will help when you are trouble-shooting the problem.

Comment: I don't see any certainty in timeouts being due to something in the networking layer.   An application can receive a packet and then run into a problem that causes it to fail to respond.

Comment: There is one more cause of failure, and that is if the service is taking an inordinate amount of time.  I.e. the response requires significant time to compile the results.

Answer (score 1):

The *only* underlying reason is that [a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html).

This means that the program *deliberately asked for* a timeout, then it asked to read data or accept a connection, and there was no data or no connection before the timeout ran out. There is no default timeout on sockets - you have to ask for one.

(It seems to also apply when connecting to a server, but the documentation doesn't mention it)

In your case the library "okhttp3" is making the socket. okhttp3 might have a timeout by default and a way to change it. See [How to set connection timeout with OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953819/how-to-set-connection-timeout-with-okhttp). [A value of 0 means no timeout. The default value is 10 seconds.](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/connect-timeout/)

---

Why was there no data? Assuming your network connection is okay, then the server probably didn't send any. Most likely it's taking some time to think about the request you made. 10 seconds is an eternity to make a user wait for a web page, but it's plausible for an API.

Comment: Why was there no data? Because the receiver didn't receive any. It is quite possible that the sender _did_ send data, it just didn't arrive.